# What is the tag @-ms-viewport in twitter-bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In my Twitter Bootstrap (Responsive) file, version 2.2.2, there is a tag

```
@-ms-viewport { 
    width: device-width 
}
```

I have seen `@media` and other `@`s. But there is no documentation for `@-ms-viewport`. Is it related to Microsoft or IE? Why is it the first style declaration?

Comment: `-ms-` is a [vendor prefix](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css-vendor-prefixes.htm)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can read more about it here:

[@-ms-viewport rule (Internet Explorer)](http://web.archive.org/web/20141231092403/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869615(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Specifies properties that describe the viewport.

Comment: It's important to note that moving forward the @viewport will become the standard and the <meta> tag equivalent should only be maintained for compatibility.

Comment: @Markus as of today in oct 2021 the exact opposite happened the at viewport has been retired and there is no support while the <meta> tag is here to stay it seems

Comment: For anyone else curious, `<meta name="viewport" ... />` is on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag